# XAP processing failed ERROR 2002 how to fix this

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

i am trying submit app to windows phone app but it than fails saying "XAP processing Failed " with error code 2002 and according to  them the solution for this is as below

> The localized title for [file name] is missing or empty. Update your file and then try again.

but where it is , how to get it done .and i just want my app to be in English default language , i dont want any other localized language support in my app .so i how to solve this problem please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was problem of total size of mainpage.cs of mainpage.xaml file i reduce the code from single .cs file and error was gone

Comment: As strange as it sounds, I had the same issue. Had a .cs file that was around 12k lines long (don't ask why!!!), compiled perfectly and ran very well in the Emulator, but failed submission.  Broke it up into two smaller files, and it submitted perfectly.   The error code is not entirely appropriate.